# Slider for Bootstrap (ползунок для цен)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, rangeslider

В интернет-магазине использую библиотеку [Slider for Bootstrap](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/), для вывода ползунка выбора диапазона цены.

Диапазон цен может быть от 100 ₽ до 45000000 ₽. 
Соответственно, если пользователь хочет отфильтровать товары по цене до 7 тысяч рублей, то у него это не получится.

Требуется сделать так, чтобы при движении ползунка, значение инкремента увеличивалось.

У этой библиотеки, есть параметр `scale: 'logarithmic'` который делает примерно то, что нужно. Но, делает в неправильном порядке (на убывание). Требуется, чтобы не было скачков при движении ползунка.

Вот есть тема [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846221/logarithmic-slider) — на основе этой темы разработчики библиотеки и реализовали функционал `scale: 'logarithmic'` - в исходниках библиотеки, есть ссылка на эту тему.
В этой теме первый ответ — это и есть решение! Как можно внедрить этот функционал в библиотеку?

Comment: https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/#example-15 вот примеры с вашей ссылки. скачки потому что step=10 в настройках, а про убывание не понял.

Comment: @teran этот пример я видел.

Скачки, имел ввиду, что когда вы двигаете ползунок, с 10 до 20, то диапазок движения ползунка больше, чем при движении с 20 до 30 и т.д.

Т.е. логарифмическая функция должна применяться только к значениям ползунка, но не отражаться на поведении ползунка.

Comment: Т.е. должно быть также, как и в первом примере из ссылки 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846221/logarithmic-slider